# Create multiple website templates with django cms or any tool

Tags: django, django-templates, content-management-system, django-cms

Can Django be used to create a website for creating custom websites depending on the user needs? There will be more than one template and each user will have a custom url for their websites.

I don't know if this can this be achieved with Django CMS.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it is possible but it requires ton of work, because you need to write bunch of templates, or/and logic that handles templates.

You could write `TemplateMixin`, that depending on passed domain, or kwarg in url changes the template in the `View`. So, for example, it could look like that:

```py
class TemplateMixin:
    template_name = None
    request = None
    model = None

    def get_template_names(self):
        """
        Return a list of template names to be used for the request.

         Must return a list. May not be called if render_to_response() is overridden.
        """
        db_settings = Settings.objects.get_or_create()[0]
        if self.template_name is None:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                'TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of '
                '\"template_name\" or an implementation of \"get_template_names()\"')
        template = db_settings.website_template
        ready_template = '/'.join([template, self.template_name])
        return [ready_template]
```

There are also solutions for handling multiple domains, so you could detect what current domain is via `self.request` in `get_template_names` method. The templates are handled by prefix. The kwargs also should be in `self.kwargs`, so you can detect which site you need to present via custom namespace url.

You can also create `WebsiteSettings` model that handles various templates, and is manageable via simple custom dashboard panel, and belongs to user, or user groups. The fields that it should have is 'template' with `choices` attribute, relation to `User` (or `CustomUser` model), and bunch of settings you want to give a user (or you could have different model('s) for that).

The solution I bring here is simple to show the idea - but it can be insufficient, to accomplish what you really want you must write the whole mixins, views etc. logic yourself.